# How do I create a new delegate type based on an existing one, in C#?

Tags: c#, inheritance, delegates

Is there any way that I can create a new delegate type based on an existing one? In my case, I'd like to create a delegate `MyMouseEventDelegate` which would have the same functionality as `EventHandler<MouseEventArgs>`.

Why do I want this? To take advantage of **compile-time type-checking**, of course! This way, I can have two different delegates: `MyRightClickHandler` and `MyLeftClickHandler`, and never the twain shall be confused - even if they are both functionally identical to `EventHandler<MouseEventArgs>`.

Is there syntax to do this sort of thing?

Oh, and code like:

```
using MyRightClickHandler = EventHandler<MouseEventArgs>
```

isn't good enough. It doesn't do any type-checking, since it doesn't actually create a new type. And I'd have to paste such a line into every code file in which I would refer to `MyRightClickHandler`.

Comment: I've amended the title to make it clear that you're talking about delegate types, not delegate instances. Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well, it's as simple as copying the delegate declaration from the original. There's nothing in C# to do this automatically, but I can't see it's much of a burden:

```
public delegate void MyLeftClickHandler(object sender, MouseEventArgs e);
public delegate void MyRightClickHandler(object sender, MouseEventArgs e);
```

It's not like `MouseEventHandler` is going to change any time soon...

Have you actually been bitten by bugs due to using the wrong delegates in the wrong places though? I can't remember ever having found this a problem myself, and it seems to me you're introducing more work (and an unfamiliar set of delegates for other developers) - are you sure it's worth it?

Comment: Wow. I guess I ought to think and use better common-sense next time :-)

Comment: It is not a burden but it doesn't allow polymophism on delegates.

Answer (score 8):

I you only want to achieve compile time type checking I guess it would be enough to create specialized EventArgs classes for the cases that you describe. That way you can still take advantage of the pre-defined delegates:

```
class RightMouseButtonEventArgs : MouseEventArgs {}
class LeftMouseButtonEventArgs : MouseEventArgs {}

EventHandler<RightMouseButtonEventArgs>
EventHandler<LeftMouseButtonEventArgs>
```

Answer (score 8):

No. According to the [C# documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173172.aspx), delegate types are sealed, and you cannot create a new delegate type that inherits from an existing one.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't believe [jon-skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).  I had to try it for myself.  He was right.

```
public void F(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {}; 
public MyLeftClickHandler l;
public MyRightClickHandler r;
public void Test()
{
    l = F;  // Automatically converted.
    r = F;  // Automatically converted to a different type.
    l = r;  // Syntax error.  Incompatible types.
    l = new MyLeftClickHandler(r);  // Explicit conversion works.
}
```

That wasn't obvious!

Comment: _"I didn't believe `jon-skeet`"_  :giggle:

Comment: Sacrilege, i say in the name of Jon Skeet