# Can I "inherit" a delegate? Looking for ways to combine Moq and MSpec without conflicts around It

Tags: c#, inheritance, delegates, mspec

I have started to use [MSpec](http://github.com/machine/machine.specifications) for BDD, and since long ago I use Moq as my mocking framework. However, they both define `It`, which means I can't have `using Moq` and `using Machine.Specifications` in the same code file without having to specify the namespace explicitly each time I use `It`. Anyone who's used MSpec knows this isn't really an option.

I googled for solutions to this problem, and [this blogger](http://jhollingworth.com/?p=112) mentions having forked MSpec for himself, and implemented paralell support for `Given`, `When`, `Then`.

I'd like to do this, but I can't figure out how to declare for example `Given` without having to go through the entire framework looking for references to `Establish`, and changing code there to match that I want either to be OK.

For reference, the `Establish`, `Because` and `It` are declared in the following way:

```
public delegate void Establish();
public delegate void Because();
public delegate void It();
```

What I need is to somehow declare `Given`, so that everywhere the code looks for an `Establish`, `Given` is also OK.

Comment: Dupe: [how-do-i-create-a-new-delegate-type-based-on-an-existing-one-in-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861835/how-do-i-create-a-new-delegate-type-based-on-an-existing-one-in-c?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using fully qualified type names to overcome the clash, you could use "using" to alias the type names, e.g.:

```
using MadeUpName = System.Windows.Forms.SomeClass;
```

You can then use MadeUpName without the clash.

```
MadeUpName obj = new MadeUpName();
```

Comment: This is an acceptable workaround at the moment, but it does mean that I have to include the using statements at the top of each spec file. Is there no way I can avoid that?

Comment: Not as far as I know. Are you adding your spec files through VS? You may be able to modify the existing VS template to include the boilerplate, in the same way as you get a load of default using imports in the bog standard class template file.

Comment: I know the answer was not along the inheriting from delegates lines (can't be done), but the solution does get the job done - no upvote? :)